# Finding area of two triangles sharing a side.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to find the areas of the two triangles below:
[image]

My attempt was to use a systems of equations as follows:
$$DG^2=\left(49386.7\right)^2+\left(103799.2\right)^2-2\cdot \left(49386.7\right)\cdot \left(103799.2\right)\cdot \:cos\left(x\right),\:$$
$$DG^2=\left(58741\right)^2+\left(68435\right)^2-2\cdot \left(58741\right)\cdot \left(68435\right)\cdot \:cos\left(z\right)$$
$$\:cos\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(49386.7\right)^2+\left(103799.2\right)^2-DG^2}{2\cdot \left(49386.7\right)\cdot \left(103799.2\right)}$$
However when I try solving it on Wolfram Alpha it says that the third equation gives an invalid value. Why is that? How else can I possibly find the areas of these triangles?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not enough information is given, unless you are trying to solve for the area in terms of an unknown measure.

Comment: Subtracting the first from the second will eliminating DG leaving x as the only variable to be solved.